# Insert Data into MySQL using JDBC that have reference to another table

Tags: java, mysql, database, xampp

I have two tables in my database (I use MySQL and xampp as the tool). I need to insert 5000 data to database that one of the column has reference to another column in another table.

Here my tables.

table dictionary

```
dict_id |         dictionary        |
------------------------------------
   1    | I know You were in trouble|
   2    | Good to see you           |
   3    | What are you doing?       |
   .    |          . . .            |
   .    |          . . .            |
 5000   |          . . .            |
```

Table status

```
user_id | dict_id | status|
---------------------------
    1   |    2    | bad   |
    1   |    1    | good  |
    1   |    3    | bad   |
    2   |    1    | bad   |
    3   |    3    | good  |
---------------------------
```

I had done with my table dictionary. My question is how I can do that to my table status? I have 500 users and more than 5000 data. Do I need to store it manually? What am I supposed to do? I don't have any clue to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for INSERT ... SELECT ... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

```
INSERT INTO status SELECT dict_id, user_id FROM dictionary, users WHERE ....
```

Its not clear where user_id or where the status really comes from but that might be a good start?